# Rails assets:precompile is trying to compile too many files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I cannot run rake assets:precompile in my App but it try to compile partials.

I have:

```
  config.assets.precompile += %w( active_admin.js active_admin.css )
```

and nothing else.

Rake give error on file:

```
Undefined variable: "$selected-row-color".
  (in /home/eloyesp/projects/diputados/app/assets/stylesheets/expedientes_index.css.scss)
```

Why does it is trying to precompile this file?

---

found [this pull request is related](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2876)

and [this test show that](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/railties/test/application/assets_test.rb#L76) this should not happen.

My rails version is 3.2.2

Comment: Um, what? The asset system is trying to compile a .scss file in the `app/assets/` hierarchy. Which is exactly what it should be doing. There's a bug in the .scss file, so it fails, but it's doing everything right.

Comment: The name is not application.css nor application.css.scss so it should not be compiled.

Comment: By default, the asset system will compile files from app/assets. One of those files has an bug, which is why you see an error message. You've _added_ 2 files to the precompile-list, yes, but the error is caused by one of the other files. If you only want to precompile the 2 files and nothing else, use `=` instead of `+=`

Comment: @Flambino This would prevent compiling other assets (images) so is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it: it was **not** trying to compile `expedientes_index.css.scss` it was compiling `application.css.scss` (this had `*= require_tree .` that it shouldn't in this app).

The problem was because the error didn't name the file it was trying to compile.